# How to install CUDA on Debian 9 (Stretch) without breakint the system?

Tags: debian, nvidia

There are some answers considering the installation of the cuda drivers on debian 9 (stretch) here, however as far as I can judge, they mix Ubuntu with Debian sources, and this probably crashed my system when I followed their instructions.

---

There is a tutorial on the official Debian site how to install it without creating a "FrankenDebian" (this is how they call it), but it is for Debian 8 (Jessy).

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

I do not know enough, to understand how I should adjust this tutorial to the needs of Debian 9 (stretch)

Comment: it is related, but it only covers the first step of this more comprehensive question.

Comment: I followed the Nvidia instruction on my Jessie and messed the graphic subsystem completely. I didn't manage to repair it and ended up with the clean install. I know, this is just a single experience, but I would not try that on my productive system again.

Comment: Have you read your link? they seem to have added instructions for debian 9